# How does being a postdoc work?

Tags: postdocs

I've been recently completing what I want to do after I obtain a Ph. D. since my Ph. D will be in math there will be choices for me to go into industry. However, I'm wondering it there's a timeline to go into being a postdoc and conducting further research. Can one postdoc at multiple places?  Especially if they have been in industry for a while (my end goal is to go into academia).

Comment: Note that postdoc positions generally require you to have obtained a PhD not too long ago (it varies how long, but rarely more than 5 or maybe 6 years).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was not aware of this

Comment: Some postdocs in the United States require your PhD to be finished two years or less before in order for you to be eligible to apply.

Comment: The details will usually be mentioned in the job posting, so it is a good idea to take a look at the ones that might interest you to see what sort of times are mentioned.

Comment: The previous comments about the timing requirements for postdoc positions are correct. On the other hand, people who have worked in industry for some time can be hired into tenure-track or tenured positions in math departments.

Comment: This needs to be narrowed down some to be answerable, since the methods and assumptions around postdoc vary wildly between fields.  In computer science, postdoc used to be virtually unheard of.  In many areas of biology, there is an assumption that you will do many years of postdoc, often in a very rigid environment.  On of my colleagues told me of a subfield in which there is essentially a formal "clearinghouse" run by the professional society that matches graduates and postdocs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a wide variety of postdocs available, which makes summarization challenging.  Typically, the goal of a postdoctoral fellowship is to broaden your research experience and better prepare you for a career in academia immediately after your graduation with a PhD.  Postdocs are extremely common in the sciences.  (Perhaps [they are](http://www.ethanperlstein.com/postdocalypse-now/) a [bit too](https://chroniclevitae.com/news/958-the-rogue-scientist-s-guide-to-surviving-the-postdocalypse) common.)  As mentioned by Andreas Blass in the comments, many positions are advertised seeking recent (i.e., within 2-4 years) PhD grads.

It is possible to do multiple postdocs sequentially, though anything beyond two is a bit of a red flag for being hired in academia.  It's probably best to think of your PhD graduation as starting a clock for academic positions.  If you haven't gotten an academic position within five years, then the application process becomes quite different.  If you are planning on waiting this long, you would likely be better off working in industry or at a research lab and attempting to make the transition back to academia without doing a postdoc.  (I'm not familiar with this process, so I won't comment on it.)

If you're interested in more information about postdocs, I can recommend the following sources:

1. The [National Postdoctoral Association](http://www.nationalpostdoc.org/) has terrible web design, but there's lots of good information there if you can dig for it.
2. Georgia Tech's [Office of Postdoctoral Services](http://postdocs.gatech.edu/) has a lot of great information, albeit targeted towards GT Postdocs.  You should also look to see if the places you're applying have a similar organization.
3. Peter Feibelman's [A PhD is Not Enough!: A Guide to Survival in Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465022227) is a relatively short book on how to succeed as a postdoc.  It was recently updated, and is probably the best generic introduction to life as a postdoc available.
4. The [CRA's Postdoc Best Practices Guide](http://cra.org/resources/bp-view/best_practices_memo_computer_science_postdocs_best_practices/) is intended for postdocs in computing, but I don't see why it wouldn't be valuable to a broader audience.  It's much shorter than Feibelman's book, and covers some of the same ground.